# Knime windows scheduler task without server

Tags: scheduled-tasks, knime

I'd like to run my knime workflow automated (with some period)  without Knime server. I tried the windows task scheduler but it asks the "program to start with"(I also configured always open with knime option). 
I'm not sure that it's going to run the workflow even if it opens. How can I make it automated without knime server ?
[image]
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KNIME Analytics Platform can be run in batch mode from the command line. This allows you to programmatically run a workflow without using the GUI. The below command executes a workflow stored in folder `workspace` with name `Knime_project`:

```
knime.exe -consoleLog -noexit -nosplash -application org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION -workflowDir="workspace/Knime_project"
```

More information and examples can be found in the [KNIME FAQ](https://www.knime.com/faq#q12). Once you get your workflow successfully running from command line, you might use the scheduler to run your command frequently.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Thank you @Daniel this is what I was looking for.